# add multiple price like sale price woocommerce with scheduling with date

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to add multiple price like sale price with schedule.

Example:

```
       My Price 1: 

       Valentine Day Price:
```

Comment: Hey! welcome to stackoverflow. If you're having a programming issue please post enough code to reproduce the problem and let us know what you have been trying. Check out this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that StackOverflow is a platform for professional coders and enthusiasts. It is not a code writing service. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some inspiration.